# Find equation of plane in R3 that passes through point (2,3,5) and contains the line with equation

Tags: linear-algebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TI4k.png)

I'm really confused on where to continue with this problem, any help would be wonderful!

Comment: See these - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/253635/1157207 , https://www.cuemath.com/questions/find-the-equation-of-the-plane-passing-through-the-point-0-7-7-and-containing-the-line-x-1-3-y-32-z-21/ , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640463/equation-of-a-plane-containing-a-point-and-a-line ,